# Django editing profile

Tags: python, django

I want to do the following:
- Allow site users to edit their email address in a form.
- If their email already exists in the database, they see an error as long as the email they put in belongs to someone else other than themselves. So if person A puts the email test@yahoo.com and person B has that email already-there's an error. If person A puts the email test@yahoo.com and that is the same email that she has been using, then there is no error.

How can I do this using Django?

I have the following code:

```
class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'email', 'last_name', )

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if email == self.email:
            return email

        try:
            DjangoUser.objects.get(email=email)
            raise ValidationError('Email is already taken.')
        except DjangoUser.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        return email

    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
```

The problem is self.email does not give me the person's current email. :(

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the current user (stored in `request`), more precisely his/her e-mail.

So what I would suggest as a workaround would be to pass or set the `request`/`e-mail`/`user` in the form.

An example of setting the `user` in your `form` through the `view` after the form is created:

```
# views.py
def someview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_edit_form = UserEditForm(request.POST)
        user_edit_form.actual_user = request.user
        if user_edit_form.is_valid():
            do_some_stuff()
```

The approach is pretty much the same if you use class-based views. This way, in your form you can check with:

```
self.actual_user.email == self.cleaned_data['email']
```

Naturally you can set only the user's email if you don't need the whole user.